# Translate part of a PDF using Azure Document Translation

Tags: azure

I have a PDF generated by a third party application which is in English, the document is over three pages and I need to translate this document into different languages.

I can translate the whole PDF using Azure Document Translation service, however, there are sections of the PDF I don’t want translated.

I don’t see any way of performing this in the console / API.

Is this possible? I asked ChatCPT which stated it was possible by marking the document or specifying a range, the link ChatGPT provided did not work so perhaps this function has been removed.

We don’t want to make any changes to the application which generates the PDF, and only want to translate parts of the PDF.

Would appreciate any feedback about how this can be done in Azure Document Translation, without translating the whole document.

Thank you

Comment: Azure Document Translation does not directly provide a built-in feature to selectively translate specific parts of a document while leaving other parts untranslated, you can only achieve this by pre-processing your document before translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a glossary that designates specific meanings for the unique context.  You can use this glossary to restrict Document Translation from translating certain terms or product names by providing the same source and [target text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/translator/document-translation/how-to-guides/create-use-glossaries)[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/translator/document-translation/how-to-guides/create-use-glossaries).

***For example, if the document contains brand names or domain-specific terminology, you can ensure they remain untranslated by including them in the glossary.***

> We don’t want to make any changes to the application which generates the PDF, and only want to translate parts of the PDF.

If you can't modify the application and want to translate parts means, there is the only chance is that you need to "extracting the desired content, translating it, and then optionally saving the translated text to a separate file."

```py
# Azure Document Translation service credentials and endpoint
endpoint = "https://<YOUR_TRANSLATION_ENDPOINT>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

# Initialize Document Translation client
translation_client = DocumentTranslationClient(endpoint, credential)

# Function to extract text from PDF
def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path, start_page, end_page):
    text = ""
    with open(pdf_path, "rb") as pdf_file:
        pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
        for page_num in range(start_page - 1, min(end_page, pdf_reader.numPages)):
            page = pdf_reader.getPage(page_num)
            text += page.extractText()
    return text

# Function to translate text
def translate_text(text, source_language, target_language):
    # Submit translation request
    poller = translation_client.begin_translation(
        inputs=[{
            "source_url": None,
            "source_text": text,
            "source_language": source_language,
            "target_language": target_language,
            "glossaries": None
        }],
        polling_interval=5
    )
    translation_result = poller.result()
    return translation_result[0].translated_text

# Path to input PDF file
pdf_path = "input.pdf"

# Extract text from specific pages
start_page = 1
end_page = 3
text_to_translate = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path, start_page, end_page)

# Translate the extracted text
source_language = "en"  # Source language (English)
target_language = "fr"  # Target language (French)
translated_text = translate_text(text_to_translate, source_language, target_language)

# Specify the output file path for translated text
output_file_path = "translated_output.txt"

# Write the translated text to the output file
with open(output_file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
    output_file.write(translated_text)

print(f"Translated text saved to: {output_file_path}")
```

- Above code allows the input PDF file path (`pdf_path`), the range of pages to extract text from (`start_page` and `end_page`), the source and target languages for translation, and the output file path for the translated text.

***If you extract from Azure storage container check below.***

```py
# Specify the input PDF document (replace with your actual file path)
input_document_url = "https://give-ur-blob.blob.core.windows.net/testsurya/260KB.pdf"

# Define the translation ranges (page numbers or specific sections)
# Example: Translate pages 1-3 and 5-7
translation_ranges = [
    {"start_page": 1, "end_page": 3},
    {"start_page": 5, "end_page": 7}
]

# Specify the target language
target_language = "es"  # Replace with your desired target language code (e.g., "es" for Spanish)

# Create a translation job
job_details = client.begin_translation(
    source_url=input_document_url,
    targets=[{"target_url": None, "language": target_language}]
).result()


# Get the translated document URL
translated_document_url = job_details.documents[0].translated_document_url

print(f"Translated document URL: {translated_document_url}")
```

**Output:**

[image]